# wp_editor returning invalid html

Tags: wp-editor

I am using `wp_editor` in my plugin.

It is displayed on the page as:

```
<?php wp_editor(get_option('edpp_card_design'), 'edpp_card_design', array(
  'textarea_name' => 'edpp[card_design]'
)); ?>
```

When I post the form it is returning invalid HTML, doing a `print_r` on the posted data returns something that looks like this:

```
<span style="\&quot;color:" #ff0000;\"=""><strong>Some Test School</strong></span>
```

Viewing it Text in the editor has it right at

```
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Some Test School</strong></span>
```

I don't get why this is happening, am I missing something? Is `wp_editor` configured wrong here or should I be running the output through a function before I use it?

Comment: It almost looks like you have a rogue opening quote somewhere that's throwing off the HTML. Have you turned on debugging to see if there's any errors or warnings?

Comment: with WP_DEBUG enabled I get nothing outputed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the output from `wp_editor` is safe to save to a database. It needs passing through `stripslashes()` before echoing into HTML.

Comment: There's also [`esc_textarea()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_textarea) which may work too.